# TreeMap as a generic class

Tags: java, generics, treemap

I want to learn TreeMap from Java Collections and make an example code with generics.

I had the idea of making "an ordered list" of whatever type you want it to be, (e.g)
 where Employees are ordered alphabetical by name and Integer are their IDs or  where Students are ordered by their ID and Student is a custom Object.

I want some help or guidance to learn this Java Collection and solve this problem.

**My generic class**

```
public class GenericTreeMap<E1, E2> extends TreeMap<E1, E2>{
    private E1 e1;
    private E2 e2;

    public GenericTreeMap(E1 e1, E2 e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }

    public void printTypes() {
        System.out.println("Key type: " + e1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Value type: " + e2.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
Empleado e = new Empleado();
GenericTreeMap<Empleado, Integer> treeMap = new GenericTreeMap<>(e, "");
treeMap.put(new Empleado(1, 1500), "Ricardo");
treeMap.put(new Empleado(2, 1200), "Gerardo");
treeMap.put(new Empleado(3, 300), "Becario");
treeMap.put(new Empleado(4, 0), "Esclavo");

treeMap.values();
```

**Expected Output**

Key type: Employee

Value type: Integer

Edit: My code does not work as intended.

Comment: i don't undertsan what is your problem?. If you want to store a type generic, you can use  hashmap or tree or map

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez I want to create a generic class which extends from TreeMap but this only outputs NullPointerException.

Comment: You are using the default constructor, not the one defined by you: this means that e1 and e2 are not initialized and then you get NullPointer .  Anyway,  as @metallurd's answer, this is not about ordering

Comment: @Renato I know there are better ways to implement this but I have to follow this absurd assigment with this conditions. It has to be a generic class which extends from TreeMap

Answer (score 1):

Use List, not Map. Implement *Comparable* in your element class, or implement a *Comparator*, or use *Comparator* in combination with streams. Map is a wrong tool to implement what you need.

There is of course a possibility to keep elements ordered in the *TreeMap*. Depending on what order you need you can implement a *Comparator* and provide it when you create a *TreeMap*. But handling it *may* be more complex than using a *List*.

Comment: It is a requirement to create a generic class which extends from TreeMap. It's homework I can't understand either.

Comment: Yeah I have the comparator ready for both Students and Employees. But the assigment was rejected because it had to be done withing a generic class. I will update with the comparators if you want to.

Comment: @WhiteGlove: May be they expect you to implement *Comparable* in your classes *Students* and *Employees*. This would be less flexible than using *Comparator*, because only one comparison algorithm can be used, but everything other will work as in case of *Comparators*.